# Problems on Sylow Theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $p\in\mathbb{N}$  be a prime and let
$$(ab)^p=a^pb^p,~~ \forall a,b\in G$$

> Prove that $G$ has a unique Sylow $p-$subgroup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Sylow theorems, $a \in G$ is an element of some sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ if and only if $a^{p^n} = 1$ for some $n>0$. Consider the set $S = \{a \in G: \exists n>0 \text{ such that } a^{p^n}=1\}$.

1. Show that the assumed property implies that $S$ is a subgroup.
2. By either the Sylow theorems or Cauchy's theorem applied to the group $S$, this subgroup must be a $p$-subgroup of $G$.
3. Since every other $p$-subgroup must be contained in $S$, $S$ forms a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, which is exactly what a Sylow $p$-subgroup is. Uniqueness follows immediately.